# caracter especial '@' en etiqueta xml

Tags: xml

El editor me da error al intentar introducir una @ dentro de la etiqueta de inicio y cierre en xml. He probado a cambiar la @ por &#64 pero el problema persiste. ¿Alguna idea de cómo solventarlo?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los elementos o etiquetas de XML tienen estas reglas para darles nombre:

- Deben comenzar por una letra o un guión bajo.
- No pueden comenzar por las letras XML en ninguna combinación de mayúsculas o minúsculas.
- Pueden contener letras, dígitos, guiones, guiones bajos y puntos.
- No pueden contener espacios.

Por lo que parece que no se especifica la arroba como carácter válido.

Depende de lo que quieras hacer, podrías usar una transformación XSLT para renombrar elementos, pero si el resultado lleva arrobas no se consideraría un documento XML válido.

Más info:

- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp
- https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-NameStartChar